# loading picture from library gets rotated

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am writing an android app and I am offering the user the ability to load a picture from the library.

The picture is loaded but rotated 90 degrees. Sometimes it is rotated -90 degrees.
How can  I load the picture "the same way" it shows when you view it by your libray?
So if it is rotated then sure load it rotated it. But if it is correct, then it should be loaded the same way

Thank you very much

Sorry guys I should've added my code, Here it is:

```
        try {
            Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, REQUEST_CHOOSE_IMAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

        switch(requestCode) { 
        case REQUEST_CHOOSE_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                InputStream imageStream;
                try {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 8;
                    Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options );
                    ivPictureChosen.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage); //ivPictureChosen is image view to display the picture

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't pick image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no concept of an image being rotated.  "So if it is rotated then sure load it rotated" makes no sense.  Only you can rotate it so please show the code where you load the image and set it to your ImageView.  Relevant code only please, not just a dump.

Comment: You may need to examine the exif Orientation tag, and rotate the image to correct it to appear "right side up".

Comment: FWIW, googling for `android read exif orientation` brings back some apropos results.

Comment: I added my code for your reference as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm *attempting* the code below.  It examines the orientation of the image and then rotates it accordingly.  The issue I have is running out of memory and have yet to find a solution to exceeding the VM buget.  This should work on smaller images and when your app is not already using a lot of memory.

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(filePath);
                int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotateBitmap(bitmap, 180);
                    break;

                }

public static void rotateBitmap(final Bitmap source, int mRotation){
    int targetWidth=source.getWidth();
    int targetHeight=source.getHeight();
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(mRotation,source.getWidth()/2,source.getHeight()/2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, new Paint());
}
```